# How to download ALL the pictures of a webpage and save them in their original names?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I coded a small Python script to download a picture from a website using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
class FirefoxTest:
    def firefoxTest(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://www.sitew.com")
        self.r=self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
        self.uri=self.r.get_attribute("src")
        self.g=urllib.request.urlopen(self.uri)
        with open("begueradj.png",'b+w') as self.f:
            self.f.write(self.g.read())             
if __name__=='__main__':
    FT=FirefoxTest()
    FT.firefoxTest()
```

How can I modify my code in order to:

1. download all the pictures on the webpage ?
2. not to name the image I downloaded and keep their default name instead ?

Comment: Could you describe the steps you would take, if you were to do this manually? Write those steps out on a piece of paper. Start translating those steps into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to [`find_elements_by_tag_name`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_tag_name). For downloading files, I'd use [`urllib.urlretrieve()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) - it would extract the filename from the url for you:

```
images = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for image in images:
    src = image.get_attribute("src")
    if src:
        urllib.urlretrieve(src)
```

Comment: There is a bug around `for image in images`. It says: `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable`

Comment: @begueradj make sure there is `find_elements_by_tag_name()`, not `find_element_by_tag_name()` - watch `s`.

Comment: Yes, I missed the 's' indeed. I tried your first and second solutions: both of them work as I dreamt of. You are the best man in this life Alexander. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ruby gems  **nokogiri** to open the web page and download the images using their xpath.

---

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

f = open('sample.flv')
begin
    http.request_get('/sample.flv') do |resp|
        resp.read_body do |segment|
            f.write(segment)
        end
    end
ensure
    f.close()
end
```

---

Comment: The question is python-specific.