# Save image with urllib.urlretrieve()

Tags: python, selenium, urllib

I am trying to access the following [link](http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=SPY&p=W&b=5&g=0&i=t22668158720&r=1479516224284) through my script and download the chart which comes up.

I was implementing it using the accepted response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913217/how-to-download-all-the-pictures-of-a-webpage-and-save-them-in-their-original-na) but when I try to open the file, I get error: `The file “test.png” could not be opened because it is empty.`

Here is my code snippet:

```
import urllib
image_element = driver.find_element_by_id('chartImg')
src = image_element.get_attribute("src")
if src:
    urllib.urlretrieve(str(src), "test.png")
```

Next I tried to debug further and changed my code to

```
if src:
    a, b = urllib.urlretrieve(str(src), "test.png")
    print a, b.items()
```

which gives me the following output:

```
test.png
[('date', 'Sat, 19 Nov 2016 01:19:20 GMT'), ('connection', 'Keep-Alive'), ('content-length', '0'), ('server', 'BigIP')]
```

Does anyone know why 'content-length' is '0'? I think this is the reason downloaded file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around...take screenshot

```
    image_element = driver.find_element_by_id('chartImg')
    src = image_element.get_attribute("src")
    if src:
        driver.get(src)
        driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```

Don't know if there is a better way but this does the job

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for this is because the image you are scraping does not contain an extension. If you run this code for example:

```
src = "http://i.imgur.com/2C7Csq6.png"
urllib.urlretrieve(src, "test.png")
```

The PNG file works, and it is the exact same image. I've tried looking for ways to do this without having to upload to an image sharing service where it would provide an extension, but haven't found anything. I've also tried adding `.png` to the original `src` string, but that didn't work either. My guess is this is a website-specific problem. Hopefully you can find a workaround for this, good luck!

Comment: thanks, I agree that it would work with any image extension (*.png, *.jpeg) but in this case since the image does not have extension, I am looking for any possible tips